# How to get rid of Warning C4142 in a visual studio project?

Tags: c, visual-studio, typedef, compiler-warnings

In my project, I am using a third party stack that includes a header file containing typedefs. My project also contains a header file that contains the same typedefs. I am getting the following warning in visual studio.

**1. Warning    C4142   'int32_t': benign redefinition of type**

**2. Warning    C4142   'uint32_t': benign redefinition of type**

third_party_stack.h contains

```
typedef signed long     int32_t;    /* Signed 32 bit data       */
typedef unsigned long   uint32_t;   /* Unsigned 32 bit data     */
```

My project includes stdint.h which contains this

```
typedef int                int32_t;
typedef unsigned int       uint32_t;
```

In my project I am including the headers in this order

```
My_project.h
third_party_stack.h
```

What should I do in order to get rid of the warning (I am using C language). Thanks.

Comment: Please see [warning pragma](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/warning?view=msvc-160).

Comment: `#pragma warning(disable: 4142)` in the source or `/wd4142` in the compiler flags.

Comment: You might file a bug report/feature request with *third_party* to use standard types instead of homebrew stuff. `stdint.h` has been around for quite a while.

Comment: The point here is not to suppress the warnings but to fix it. Filing a request to the third party would take time but nevertheless is one of the ways to move forward. What could be a quick fix in the meanwhile? @Gerhardh

Comment: @4386427 Yes I do have all the source files however a part of it is in the form of compiled library.

Comment: I would find another 3rd party implementation. Their code has signs of low quality.

Comment: You should check if `long` is 32 bits and in that case a quick fix would be to remove that definition from 3rd party header and include `stdint.h` instead.

Comment: Either you have all source files (including source for libraries) or you only have binary libs. Both cannot be true at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either disable the warning, or be slightly nasty.

```cpp
#include "My_project.h"

#define int32_t thirdparty_int32_t
#define uint32_t thirdparty_uint32_t

#include "third_party_stack.h"

#undef int32_t
#undef uint32_t
```

Or simply modify the 3rd party header to include cstdint, and delete their typedefs. Then push that change back to them as a PR ;)

Comment: "... simply modify the 3rd party header to include cstdint ..."?!?!  In **C** code?